# Show that a sequence is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, poisson-distribution, lipschitz-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function, i.e. there exits some $C > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_+$, we have
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|.
$$
If $N \sim Poi(\lambda)$, $\lambda>0$, we can consider the random variable $f(N)$. Assume that $\mathbb{E}[f(N)] = 0$, i.e. $e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}f(n) = 0$.

Now, we consider the sequence
$$
a_l := \frac{l!}{\lambda^{l+1}} \sum_{n=0}^l\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}f(n).
$$
The goal is to show that $a_l$ is a bounded sequence.

**My thoughts:** I was able to prove an equivalent representation of $a_l$ given by
$$
a_l = \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(N)1_{\{N \leq l\}}]}{\lambda \mathbb{P}[N = l]}.
$$
Since
$$
a_l := \underbrace{\frac{l!}{\lambda^{l+1}}}_{\to \infty} \underbrace{{\sum_{n=0}^l\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}f(n)}}_{\to 0}
$$
it would suffice that the partial sums on the RHS converge fast enough to 0.
However, I am not sure how to proceed. It is not clear to me on how I can apply the Lipschitz condition in order to show boundedness. Some help or guidance into the right direction would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E} f(N)=0$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^l\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}f(n)=0
$$
and thus
$$
-a_l=\frac{l!}{\lambda^{l+1}}\sum_{n=l+1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}f(n)
$$

From Lipschitz, assuming $|f(0)|=a$, you immediately get that $|f(n)|\le Cn+a\le C_1 n$ for $n\ge 1$ for $C_1=C+a$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}|a_l|&\le \frac{l!}{\lambda^{l+1}}\sum_{n=l+1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}|f(n)|\\
&\le \frac{l!}{\lambda^{l+1}}\sum_{n=l+1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}C_1 n\\
&\le C_1 l!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{(k+l)!}\\
&=C_1\left[1+\frac{\lambda}{l+1}+\frac{\lambda^2}{(l+1)(l+2)}+\dots\right]\\
&\le C_1\left[1+\frac{\lambda}{1!}+\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}+\dots\right]\\&\le C_1 e^{\lambda}
\end{align}$$
which is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: That first equality is wrong. It converges to $0$ as $l\to\infty.$

Comment: Ah, you meant $\sum_0^\infty$ in the first equality, not $\sum_0^l.$